# How to query records with and without params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model Places and I have the index method in a controller. I need to get all places via request

```
/places
```

And filter places via request with query

```
/places?tlat=xxxx&tlong=xxxx&blat=xxxxx&blong=xxxx
```

What the best way to get this records? Should I check an existence of each param or are there Rails way?

```
@places = if params[tlat]&&params[blat]....
  Places.all.where("lat > ? AND long > ? AND lat < ? AND long < ?", tlat, tlong, blat, blong)
else
  Places.all
```

Comment: What should happen if only some parameters are present, e.g. just `tlat` and `blong`?

Comment: @Stefan I think that controller should return all records.

Comment: So you have to check if all parameters are present and return `Places.all` otherwise, just like in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set WHERE clauses depending on params, you can use Ursus' code which is fine.

However, if you need to apply those WHERE clauses only if a set of params are present, you can use the following:

```
@places = Place.all
if params[:blat].present? && params[:tlat].present?
  @places = @places.where(blat: params[:blat], tlat: params[:tlat])
end
# etc.
```

You could use an array of arrays to pair the associated params, kind of like what Ursus did.

Comment: or `if params.values_at(:blat, :tlat).all?(&:present?)`

Comment: @Ursus I prefer code readability over tiny gain of performances, but yeah that would also works

Comment: Mine is probably slower but if you have three or four params to check that become a very long line :D

Comment: I agree with you, especially when you know that a line of code should be 120 characters max... (looking at you rubocop!)

Comment: `@places = Place.all.fetch(params)` would produce the same result in only one line (but parsing with Ruby instead of SQL)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this if possible. Important to note the this is just one query, composed dynamically.

```
@places = Place.all
%i(tlat tlong blat blong).each do |field|
  if params[field].present?
    @places = @places.where(field => params[field]) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the query, may be it will be more understandable. As I understand Rails have no dedicated method "choose by params if exist, else choose all", and I should check an existence of params anyway. Am I right?

Comment: @AlexanderBorodin No there is no implicit way to tell Rails "if this params is present, use it, otherwise ignore it" because `nil` is not nothing, if you do `Place.where(attr: params[:attr])` and `params[:attr]` is `nil`, then the SQL query will look for Places where the `attr IS NULL`. You may be able to find a gem to do what you are looking for, or build something yourself (I can help you with that) to fit your requirements.

Comment: `has_scope` does exactly this, but it requires that you have `scope`s defined for each param you want to use it with @AlexanderBorodin

Comment: wouldn't this execute a separate database query for each `where` clause?

Comment: Nope @m.simonborg. Just build the query dinamically. It runs the query when you access the resultset

Comment: In this case the only query would run probably in the view. Not with the all method, nor with the where method.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, truly the "Rails way" (but actually just the "Ruby way") would be to extract this long conditional, and the query itself, out to their own private method. It becomes much easier to understand what's going on in the `index` action

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @places = Place.all
    apply_geo_scope if geo_params_present?
  end

  private

  def geo_params_present?
    !!(params[:tlat] && params[:blat] && params[:tlong] && params[:blong])
  end

  # A scope in the model would be better than defining this in the controller
  def apply_geo_scope
    %i(tlat tlong blat blong).each do |field|
      @places = @places.where(field => params[field]) 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the Rails' way is skinny controllers - fat models, so this would be a scope in the model which could handle the `nil` values. Best would be a QueryObject, but that's a whole new debate... ahahah

Comment: @MrYoshiji I agree, this was just easier to quickly illustrate. I'll update the answer to better represent the real rails way